# I want to stream .m3u8 format audio via video js

Tags: angularjs, html, video.js, http-live-streaming

I am working on a project which can stream audio streams that are in .m3u8 playlist (HLS playback). i am using videojs for the above said purpose.
Everything was going smoothly when i was using .m3u8 with videos in (.ts) format. The streams were playing in all major browsers. 
The code is below:

```
<script src="video.js"></script>
<script src="videojs.hls.min.js"></script>
<script>
    //myPlayer is my object for videosjs
    myPlayer.src({
          type: "application/x-mpegURL",
          src:"a_valid_HLS_stream.m3u8"
    });
    myPlayer.play();
</script>
```

and in html

```
<video id="myvideo"></video>
```

This code is working fine for HLS containing bits of `.ts` video streams.

Now my stream provider has changed the HLS streams by giving me `.m3u8` streams containing chunks of audio files in `.aac` format. 
So now all the browsers except safari in apple devices are able to play such a stream. 
Well I know the fact that HLS is natively support HLS playback but since videojs is for those who does not support the same by native.

Although i made some changes in my code like below

```
<script>
    //myPlayer is my object for videosjs
    myPlayer.src({
          type: "application/x-mpegURL; audio/x-aac",
          src:"another_valid_HLS_stream.m3u8"
    });
    myPlayer.play();
</script>
```

and in the html page

```
<audio id="myvideo"></audio>
```

i also tried by changing the src type to `application/vnd.apple.mpegurl` which was actually set in header of the `.m3u8` stream but no luck there too. 
Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Are you able to resolve this problem? How to play audio with .m3u8

Answer (score 2):

The problem is not in the client side configuration but rather in the media container. Resources ending in `.ts` contain media (audio/video) streams inside a [MPEG-TS](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/MPEG_transport_stream) container. Resources eding in `.aac` contain a single audio stream inside an [ADTS](https://github.com/videojs/videojs-contrib-hls) container. [videojs-contrib-hls](https://github.com/videojs/videojs-contrib-hls) does not support ADTS and the client configure is irrelevant.

Using ADTS instead of MPEG-TS offers a couple of percent less overhead. That's probably the reason why your provider has switched to using it.

IMHO your best options now is to contact your provider and ask him for a MPEG-TS stream instead of ADTS one.

Alternatively you can report this to the developers of [videojs-contrib-hls](https://github.com/videojs/videojs-contrib-hls) and see if they are interested in implementing this case.

Your third options is to ditch videojs-contrib-hls and pay for a commercial solution that offers this functionality. [Viblast Player](http://viblast.com/player/) is the solution I have experience with. You can see and example of playting ADTS stream [here](http://codepen.io/Viblast/pen/dGvorN).

Comment: I tried using viblast player with their public key which led my browser to stand still and made my pc like a comma patient.

Comment: It's a commercial project so If you're having troubles using it then contact their support and report your problems. Complaining in SO won't do much good.